# Como hacer que Javascript le ponga mayusculas a cada elemento de un arreglo?

Tags: javascript, es6

Tengo esta función y este `for.. of` pero no logro que los días se muestren con mayúscula por consola.

Que esta mal???

```
Array.prototype.toUpperCase = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
        days[i] = days[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + days[i].substr(1);

  }
};
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday']; 

for (const day of days) {
  console.log(day);
}
```

Comment: mmm, revisa , acabo de correr tu código y si me los muestra en mayúscula , revisa bien , no te sale ningún error

Comment: La declaración de la función que has hecho no tiene mucho sentido

Comment: Muchas gracias Anibal, Pablo,  Travv y Santiago!!! Seguramente me seguiran leyendo por aqui ya que estoy empezando a estudiar online! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que estas intentando es convertir la primera letra en mayuscula, lo cual fuera de la función que estas declarando basta con solo poner el `for` donde la primera letra la pasas a mayuscula y le añades el slice de la cadena desde el caracter con indice 1 en la cadena.

```js
/*Array.prototype.toUpperCase = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
        days[i] = days[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + days[i].slice(1);

  }
};*/
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday']; 

for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
        days[i] = days[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + days[i].slice(1);

  }

for (const day of days) {
  console.log(day);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes cambiar la forma en que declaras la variable **days** , estas utilizando `cosnt` de es6 , y el mismo no permite que el valor de los elementos del arreglo cambien, utiliza `let` en su lugar.

Ejecuta `days.toUpperCase()` antes de correr el ultimo `for`:

```
Array.prototype.toUpperCase = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
        days[i] = days[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + days[i].slice(1);

  }
};
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday']; 

days.toUpperCase()
for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
        days[i] = days[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + days[i].slice(1);

  }
```

Comment: Realmente eso no afecta, const afecta al array en sí, no a sus elementos

Comment: bueno el código que te acabo de poner esta probado y funcionando, pero algo si te falto y fue llamar a la función `toUpperCase()` antes de mostrar el arreglo, sino no se establecen los cambios

Answer (score 0):

Pasan 2 cosas con tu codigo

1. La primera es que nunca llamas al metodo toUppercase a pesar que lo estas asignando.
2. La variable `days` no esta existe o no esta en el contexto de la función.

Te dejo la soluciona del problema

```js
Array.prototype.toUpperCase = function() {
  return this.map(word => word.toUpperCase())
};
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'].toUpperCase(); 
for (const day of days) {
  console.log(day);
}
```

De esta manera no te aferras a una sola variable y siempre podrás realizar un toUpperCase a cualquier array de características similares.

Answer (score 0):

> Puedes usar esta opción como método rápido.

```js
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday']

String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.toLowerCase().replace(/(^|\s)([a-z])/g, function(m, p1, p2) { return p1 + p2.toUpperCase(); });
}

days.map((day) => {    
    console.log(day.capitalize())
})
```